# Find the supremum of $\left ( n+1 \right )^{\frac{2}{n^2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

As in the topic, my task is to find supremum and infimum of a given set $$f(n):=\left ( n+1 \right )^{\frac{2}{n^2}}, n\in \mathbb{N}$$What is funny, I managed to do this task few weeks ago and I worked out that supremum of $\left ( x+1 \right )^{\frac{2}{x^2}}, x\in \mathbb{R}$ is in $x=\frac{4}{e}$, so in $n=1$ we see that $f( 1)=2>f(2)$. Infimum, equal to $1$, we can find by noticing that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}f(n)=1$ and $ f(n)$ is decreasing.

I tried to do it again, but surprisingly I failed in the beginnig. I did the following:$$g(n):=\log f(n)=\frac{2}{n^2}\cdot\log(n+1)\Rightarrow g'(n)=\frac{2}{n^2}\cdot\left (-\frac{\log(n+1)}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1} \right)$$ Next, I searched where $g'(n)=0$, but it is nowhere near $\frac{4}{e}$. Any ideas how to get to that point? or maybe it is wrong? Any hints will be apreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: If $f(n) > f(n+1)$ for all $n > 2$, then isn't the supremum equal to $\max(f(3),f(2),f(1))$ since for all values $n > 3$, $f(3) > f(n)$?

Comment: I mean that $f(n)$ is decreasing, maybe i wrote it in a wrong way, i will edit in few seconds. thanks for noticing it :)

Comment: Ahhh, so you have shown that $f(n)$ is decreasing? If that is the case, isn't the supremum then just $f(1) = 4$?

Comment: Yes it is, but weeks ago I somehow find the point $\frac{4}{e}$ and now I cannot find it again, but I wish to get it back - maybe someone can

Comment: and yes - you are right: it is 4 not 2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $g(x) = (x+1)^{\frac{2}{x^2}}$ defined for all real numbers $x \geq 3/4 > e^{1/2} -1$. Then $g$ has derivative
$$
g^{\prime}(x) = \frac{2(1+x)^{\frac{2}{x^2}}}{x^2} \left(\frac{1}{(1+x)} - \frac{2\log(x+1)}{x}\right) = \frac{2(1+x)^{\frac{2}{x^2}}}{x^3(x+1)} \bigg(x - 2(x+1)\log(x+1)\bigg)
$$
which is negative since 
$$
x-2(x+1)\log(x+1) = x\bigg(1-2\log(x+1)\bigg) - 2\log(x+1)
$$
and $1 - 2 \log(1+x) < 0$ for all $x > e^{1/2} - 1$.
Therefore, $g$ is decreasing on $(3/4,\infty)$. What this shows is that for any $a > 3/4$
$$
\sup_{x \geq a} g(x) = g(a).
$$
Now notice that $f(n) = g(n)$ for all $n$ and thus,
$$
\sup_{n \geq 1} f(n) = \sup_{x \geq 1} g(x) = g(1) = 4.
$$
So I don't think $4/e$ is correct and it is in fact $4$.